# Add comma separated currency format while entering in a text box using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am entering amount in text box then it should append commas in between the amount (ex: I entered 123500 it should convert like 1,23,500.00 automatically when on blur) using angular js.

This should happen within the same input box.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a currency input, you can use, ng-currency :
https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency

```
<input type="text" model="yourModel" ng-currency />
```

An example is available here : http://plnkr.co/edit/u9mJqDH8UpwxDnOv8gZL?p=preview

The source code is pretty simple you can fork it, and adapt it to your code if you prefer.

Comment: How can this be made to work as you type rather than onBlur? There are undocumented options, and options that only have 1 possible value anyway

Comment: This directive doesn't support onkeypress or onkeyup events and only format the input onBlur. And this is understandable, it could be a pain to format the input onkeypress. But you can open an issue or contribute to the project if you want to support it.

Comment: I copied the relevant parts that were needed
https://pastebin.com/KHdcFye9
<input ng-model="$ctrl.myCurrency" cd-currency />
The currency can be added in. This can be used in an input field without having to blur

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="numberFilterExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 1234.56789;
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
  Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer: http://plnkr.co/edit/mO257aew7YKXaIzSwS6G?p=preview